# remove auto submit XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I just test this script and working, but I dont like auto submit style in this script, and try to remove/disable auto submit and add submit button as usual but didn't work.

```
<div id="div_data">

        <h2>Upload file</h2>
        <form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" placeholder="Select file"/>
            <span id="status"></span>
        </form>
        <progress min="0" max="100" value="0">0% complete</progress><br/><span id="prosentase"></span><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

.

```
<script>
function uploadFiles(url, files) {
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = 'loading..'; //tambahkan loading text
    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("myform"));

    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) { //bisa kita gunakan untuk multiple files
        formData.append(file.name, file);
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text'; //respondnya text

    xhr.onload = function(e) { 
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var text_ku = this.response;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = text_ku;
            //document.body.appendChild(div);
            var container = document.querySelector('#container');
            container.insertBefore(div, container.firstChild);
            document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = ''; //hilangkan loading text
        }
    };

    // Listen to the upload progress.
    var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
            progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
            document.querySelector('#prosentase').innerHTML= progressBar.value+"%";
        }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);  // multipart/form-data
}

document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('change', function(e) { 
  uploadFiles('http://example.com/upload.php', this.files);
}, false); // I have problem here

</script>
```

please help me to add submit button.
ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are listening for the `change` event. Try:

1. Listen for the `submit` event dispatched by the form
2. Add a submit button to your form.

Something like:

```
document.forms.namedItem("myform").addEventListener("submit",
    function(e) { 
      uploadFiles(...);
    }, false);
```

More info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Comment: What is the current behaviour after the change?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove the following lines

```
document.querySelector('input[type=file]').addEventListener('change',     function(e) { 
  uploadFiles('http://example.com/upload.php', this.files);
}, false); // I have problem here
```

And add a submit button as follows to your form

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="uploadFiles('http://example.com/upload.php', this);" />
```

And then change initial line of your method as :

```
function uploadFiles(url, filedata) {
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML = 'loading..'; //tambahkan loading text
    var formData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("myform"));

    files = filedata.files;
    for (var i = 0, file; file = files[i]; ++i) { //bisa kita gunakan untuk multiple files
        formData.append(file.name, file);
    }
```

For illustration purpose only, haven't run the code but this is it.

Regards